# Creating C++ library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to create a reasonable library structure and CMake file which would allow other CMake projects to easily include this library. I've found a lot of similar questions, however, none of them seems to address my exact problem.

My current structure is the following:

```
/*MyLibrary/
├── CMakeLists.txt (including lib subdirectories)
├── external/
│   └── googletest/
├── lib/
│   ├── common/
│   │   ├── CMakeList.txt (creates static lib common)
│   │   ├── include/common/*.h
│   │   └── src/*.cpp
│   ├── cipher/
│   │   ├── CMakeList.txt (creates static lib cipher)
│   │   ├── include/cipher/*.h
│   │   └── src/*.cpp
└── test/
    ├── main.cpp (code for executing google test)
    ├── CMakeLists.txt (creates unittest executable)
    ├── common/*Test.cpp
    └── cipher/*Test.cpp
*/
```

Now I want to create a project with a similar directory structure but the problem occurs when I want to create a static library in that project with the same name as one of the static libraries in `MyLibrary` (`common` for example).

I was thinking of including the library into the project using `add_subdirectory(external/MyLibrary)` in the projects CMakeLists, but that fails because the names of the static libraries collide.

Even when I solve this issue by renaming the library (which I don't in fact believe is an elegant solution), I end up with googletest conflicts because both, the library and my project, are dependent on googletest.

Is there any way to solve this easily? I was thinking of 2 possibilities:

- In the `MyLibrary` I would create one static library from all the sub-libraries called `libMyLibrary.a`and include only that library (preferred option, but I don't have a clue how to achieve it in CMake)
- Forcing the users of the library to install it and don't include the library as a project submodule (last option I would go for)

Is there some other reasonable way to solve it which would make my library compatible with most CMake projects? If not, how can I achieve at least one of the mentioned options?

**In short:** how can I create a CMake file for a library so the library is easy to include in other CMake projects?

How can I deal with redundant dependencies such as googletest?

Comment: For your single static library option, this will work:  https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library  I'm not sure it's the best option, but I've done it.  I'm not sure why two of your libraries depending on googletest should be a problem, though.

Comment: I have read several times your question and still I do not quite understand what is your problem. Please clarify.

Comment: @zzxyz, Thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: @RCYR I've rephrased my question a bit, is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a CMake file for a library so the library is easy to include in other CMake projects?

There is no universal approach for that purpose.

By including your project into another one with `add_subdirectory()`, you "open" internals of your project to other one. Aside of advantage in having the library's target ready for linking, this approach has disadvantages too. Target's collisions, cached variables collisions will be your headache, among with some other problems.

If you want your project to be included into other with `add_subdirectory`, avoid using "generic" names for your targets. E.g., use `<my_project_name>_common` instead of `common`.

Some targets you cannot rename (like `gtest`). If those targets aren't really required for your project to work, create an option for disable them:

```
option(<my_project_name>_TESTING "Enable testing" ON)
if(<my_project_name>_TESTING)
    add_subdirectory(external/googletest)
endif()
```

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085151/cmake-conflict-with-multiple-gtest/42087472#42087472) to the similar question about targets' names collision.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it doesn't quite answer my question. If it is not a good idea to include my library using `add_subdirectory()`, what is a better way to do it? Is it a good idea to create a single static library called `libmyawesomelibrary.a` and only link it to my project? If so, how can I share the library headers so I can compile the project?

Comment: Once again, there is no the best way for deliver your project for other's use. More "fundamental" one is installing your project and using it via `find_package()` call. This approach is described in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-packages.7.html). But this requires writting "config" script for your project. Approach with `add_subdirectory` is simpler to implement and use. Googletest recommends this approach for testing. You have chosen this approach, and faced with specific problems. My answer describes what to do with that problems.

Comment: Although I expected a bit different answer, you are right that you have in fact answered my question. Next time I will pay more attention to what am I actually asking.